# require php include from different paths

Tags: php, include, require

I have a small event platform that I install for a short time on different servers. Now this platform has some files in a subfolder - let's call it `/ajax/` and those files need some includes from another subfolder called `/includes/`

The URL where my site resides is always changing. So it can be `www.company.com/event/` or maybe`event.company.com`. Sometimes even both at the same time should be possible.

At the moment I use

```
require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/event/includes/config.php');
```

or

```
require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'includes/config.php');
```

Is there a possibility to write a path that always works, so there is no need to rewrite those code every time?

Comment: You can write a path relative to the current file, using `__DIR__` at the beginning.

Comment: If you use the [front controller pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_controller) with some [router](https://packagist.org/?query=router) library, things like this is much easier (since all requests share the same entry point.) Either way, the host name of the site shouldn't matter at all (since you're loading files locally from within the server and not through the web server.)